# Change attr to class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Checkout1').addClass('disabled');
    $('#voorwaarden').change(function() {
        $('#Checkout1').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked') ? null : 'disabled');
    });
});
```

The script is no change the attr disabled. But how can i change this script to this thing. When you change the #voorwaarden. Than remove the class diabled from #checkout1. And when i changed next the #voorwaarden. Than add class and going furter and furter. #voorwaarden is an checkbox.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the class "disabled"?

Comment: You'd better provide jsfiddle

Comment: I have a checkbox that is called #voorwaarden. And a button that is called #Checkout1. When i click on the checkbox. I make the checkbox green. Than than button, #checkbout1. Must remove the classed disabled. When i have not the checkbox green. Than the button, #checkout1. Must have the class disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do with `toggleClass()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Checkout1').addClass('disabled');
    $('#voorwaarden').change(function() {
        $('#Checkout1').toggleClass('disabled');
    });
});
```

**Note**: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

---

**Edited**: In case that you want to toggle 'disabled' property,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Checkout1').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#voorwaarden').change(function() {
        $('#Checkout1').prop('disabled', !$('#Checkout1').prop('disabled'));
    });
});
```

Comment: just finished editing a jsfiddle with the same code. i just used `.Click` on the checkbox instead of change. +1 jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egUQb/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but if your goal is to add the class "disabled" when the checkbox is not checked, and remove it when it is, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Checkout1').addClass('disabled');
    $('#voorwaarden').change(function() {
        $('#Checkout1').toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
});
```

[`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) will add the class if the flag is true, or remove it if the flag is false.